# RStudio window zoom when changing from laptop only to docked to monitors, auto-adjust possible?

Tags: r, rstudio

I was given a new laptop at work and when I switch back and forth from a docking station, RStudio seems to have problems realizing the change in display, while all the other programs seem to auto-detect and re-zoom appropriately.  The only fixes I've found is logging out and back into my Windows user account, or going through R-Studio's View>Zoom-in or View>Zoom-out when going back and forth between docked and undocked, which takes time.

There's not some setting I'm missing, is there, so RStudio detects the type of display and auto-adjusts? Example images below.

[image]

[image]

thank you, dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue, and there is some indication that there are plans to address this in rstudio v1.2.

https://community.rstudio.com/t/dramatic-screen-resolution-issue-see-screen-snip/3703/6

A workaround suggested here:

> You should be able to work around this by toggling the Zoom level in the Appearances pane

Answer (score 0):

RStudio is basically a browser window (chrome web application). It will render according to the resolution of the screen, at the current zoom setting. It will not change your zoom level as you switch monitors. `Ctr-` and `Ctrl+` are shortcuts for zooming in and out, where you should also see a popup with a reset (to 100%) option.

Zooming is not the same as changing font sizes, which is the preferable way of ensuring a good visual experience for a resolution.